# RubyTest errors - installing into sublime text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-test

I'm trying to install rubytest as per the rails tutorial guide

I've guided it to my rspec file:

```
 {
"erb_exec": "erb",
"ruby_unit_exec": "ruby",
"ruby_cucumber_exec": "cucumber -f pretty",
"ruby_rspec_exec": "/Users/snook3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rspec",

"ruby_unit_folder": "test",
"ruby_cucumber_folder": "features",
"ruby_rspec_folder": "/Users/snook3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/"  
}
```

but now it's giving me these errors: 
`/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /Users/snook3/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb: Not a directory`

How do I fix this?

This section of the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:tests_inside_sublime_text hitting Command-Shift-R . I've got so far, I don't want to give up now.

Comment: What tutorial you are following ?

Comment: Just posted it http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:tests_inside_sublime_text

Comment: I just came across this error, removed the package using Package Control in Sublime and reinstalled it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run Sublime from the command line and see if that fixes the issue.